# How do I represent and access elements of this multivalued data structure?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, cell-array, matrix-indexing, heterogeneous-array

I am trying to implement the [Brooks-Iyengar algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brooks%E2%80%93Iyengar_algorithm#Algorithm) for sensor fusion, and am trying to represent the following data structure in MATLAB.

```
A = {([1.5,3.2],4), ([0,2.7],5), ([0.8,2.8],4)}
```

I tried doing the following

```
B = {{[1.5,3.2],4},{[0,2.7],5}}
```

But then I don't know how to access each element, i.e. `1.5`, `3.2` and the `4` as well as the next set of values. I get one set of elements from `B{1}`, but am not able to get the individual values after.

Any ideas or pointers to appropriate links would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the current structure, you can simply continue the indexing:

```
>> B{1}

ans = 

    [1x2 double]    [4]

>> B{1}{1}

ans =

    1.5000    3.2000

>> B{1}{1}(2)

ans =

    3.2000

>> B{1}{2}

ans =

     4
```

To remove an item from the main structure you can use the following syntax `B(1) = [];`:

```
>> B = {{[1.5,3.2],4},{[0,2.7],5}}

B = 

    {1x2 cell}    {1x2 cell}

>> B(1) = []

B = 

    {1x2 cell}

>> B{1}

ans = 

    [1x2 double]    [5]

>>
```

---

You could also choose to represent the data in a [structure array](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) (with some better property naming):

```
>> s = struct('prop1',{4, 5},'prop2', {[1.5,3.2], [0,2.7]})

s = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    prop1
    prop2

>> s(1).prop1

ans =

     4

>> s(1).prop2

ans =

    1.5000    3.2000

>> s(1).prop2(2)

ans =

    3.2000
```

To remove an item, you can use the similar syntax:

```
s(1) = []
```

---

If you want to performs some operations on the data elements, you can also choose to go with the OOP approach, and create a class that represents a single data element and optionally one that represents the whole data set. Accessing the data members is natural.

Comment: That looks great. Just a follow up question, how would I remove a data entry (say, `{[1.5,3.2],4}` ) from the first structure?

Comment: Updated the answer about how to remove elements using the original or the structure array approaches.

Comment: But when I do B{1} = [], the size of the cell doesn't reduce. It has a an empty entry. Any way to remove that empty set as well?

Comment: `B{1} = []` differs from `B(1) = []`. The first one assigns an empty entry, the second one will remove the entry.

Answer (score 2):

If your MATLAB version is new enough (i.e. >= R2013b) you can use a [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) for this:

```
A = table([1.5,3.2; 0,2.7; 0.8,2.8],[4; 5; 4],'VariableNames',{'name1','name2'});
```

[image]

As you can see, the result is easy to inspect (visually) and easy to access:

```
A.name1(3,2) % is 2.8000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dead set on using cells then I'd start with `cell2mat` and see if that helps out.

```
  vals = cell2mat(B{2}) % returns the array vals=[0 2.7 5]
```

You could also simply use your data as normal matrix from the start:

```
 B = [ 1.5, 3.2, 4; 0, 2.7, 5];
```

And then utilize column 3 as your keys if that was your intent (and they are numeric). If the keys are not guaranteed numeric then a struct could be useful.

edit: DVarga gives a more detailed and useful answer, I think.